# Find matching strings using Regex in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement to filter out some of the specified strings in a given line using regx..
This can be easily achievale using string.macth(). But my requirement is little bit tricky.

I have set of keywords, that needs to be identified in a given string. (My input string contains only one expected keyword). I have to form the regX string and that will find which keyword is available in my input string .

Below the sample input and output

```
  var InString ="one_sam_get_2384823_34534";
  var keyList  = "one|two|three|four|five";
```

here my expected result is **one**

or

```
  var InString ="odfdfg_three_get_2384823_34534";
  var keyList  = "one|two|three|four|five";
```

here my expected result is **three**

earlier i used something like this **"/^one/i"**  to find out the single keyword occurance.

But i am struck up in this multi keyword approach. I appreaciate any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `keyList` to create a RegExp object:

```
InString.match(new RegExp(keyList, "i"))
```

Comment: Yeah, I believe this is the best way. +1

Comment: thanks gumbo, it works.. as CMS suggested, i read the matching keyword using Out[0]

Comment: Almost ... "onetwo_three".match(new RegExp("one|two|three", "i"))[0] will return "one", which is not what you want.

Comment: yes thats wat i want, cant directly use onetwo_three".match(new RegExp("one|two|three", "i"))[0].. it throws an exp at [0] if no keyword found... so i use a tem var to check if null then i get it from 0th idx...

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

```
function findKey (input, keyList) {
  var result = input.match(new RegExp(keyList));

  if (result) {
    return result[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: my requirement is not to pass the keywords indivitually (re.exec(inString)[0]), i have to pass all the keywords in a single expreassion and execute it.. because am not sure abt the keywords thats to be present in the inString

Comment: sorry cms.. misunderstood that... urs work perfectly.. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex of the form var regex = /(one|two|three)/;

Answer (score 0):

why don't you user a regular expression like

"**/(one|two|three|four|five)/i**"

Cheers